# How program can check if it is run under debugger on Solaris x86?

Tags: debugging, solaris

On linux I can check if TracerPid != 0:

```
# cat /proc/self/status
Name:   cat
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   12569
Pid:    12569
PPid:   24212
TracerPid:  0
....
```

How can I do in on Solaris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

If the following command display a non empty string, the process which process id is `pid` is traced:

```
pflags pid | grep flttrace
```

On older Solaris releases, `pflags` is in `/usr/proc/bin`.

Comment: So, it is releated to pr_flttrace (of type fltset_t) in /proc/pid/status. Thank you!